# SQL join for this query type

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table to store FAQ categories, and then a table to store FAQs, so now when I have to show the FAQs, I first loop through the categories, and then fetch all the FAQs under that category.

I want the output like,

```
Category 1
FAQ1, FAQ2...

Category 2
FAQ3, FAQ4
```

Is there any better way to do so ? regrading the performance, like by using JOIN when fetching the categories, to fetch the FAQs under each category together, so I have to run only 1 query.

My Code :

```
<?php

if($cache->hasItem('faq_categories'))
{
    $categories = $cache->getItem('faq_categories');
}
else
{
    $categories = getRows(array(
        'table' => 'faq_categories', 
        'where' => array('is_active' => 1)
    ));

    $cache->setItem('faq_categories', $categories);
}

?>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="globalBox">
            <div class="globalBoxInside">
                <h2 class="mainTitle">FAQs</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <?php $c = 1; foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>

                        <?php 

                        $faqs = getRows(array(
                            'table' => 'faqs', 
                            'where' => array('faq_category_id' => $cat['id'])
                        ));

                        ?>
                        <div class="faq_category">
                            <h4 class="faq_cat_title"><?php echo $cat['title']; ?> (<?php echo $cat['questions_count']; ?>)</h4>
                            <ul class="faqs_questions_list row">
                                <?php foreach($faqs as $faq) : ?>
                                <li class="col-md-6"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> <a href="<?php echo getURI('faqs'); ?>/<?php echo encryptParam('CA' . $cat['id'] . '-' .$faq['id']); ?>"><?php echo $faq['question']; ?></a></li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Appreciate your answers, Thanks.

Comment: Where is your query that you wrote to get this done with errors? You should post your query please.

Comment: @Testing There are no errors, I am just looking for a better way, see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all categories and loop them selecting faqs for each category...

pseudo-pythonesque-code:

```
categories = execute('select id, name from categoryTable order by name')
for category in categories:
    print category.name
    faqs = execute('select question, answer from faqTable where categoryId=' + category.id)
    for faq in faqs:
        print faq.question + ' - ' + faq.answer
```

Comment: This is what I am doing already, I am looking for a better solution, where I can get all the faqs associated with each category in one query, my question is, is that possible ?

Comment: you could load all your data at once using a join like `select c.name, f.question, f.answer from faqTable f left join categoryTable c on f.categoryId = c.id order by c.name, f.answer` and then loop this cursor

Comment: But this way I cannot get the output I need, see the question about the output, tell me if I am wrong, great if you can put the code here. Thanks.